# Does "save as" mean "unless"?

Tags: meaning

> The cookies will not be used to determine your identity, **save as**
>   expressly stated otherwise herein.

Does **"save as"** mean **"unless"** in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Save as" is not an expression.

Actually, in this kind of context, "save" means "except":

> The cookies will not be used to determine your identity, **except** as expressly stated otherwise herein.

---

Compare with:

> - The soap kills all germs, save a few.
> - The soap kills all germs, except a few (which happen to remain alive).

(This example might be ambiguous, the other meaning being that the soap saved a few germs)

---

> - All tools are now clean, save a few.
> - All tools are now clean, except a few (which are still dirty).

Comment: This sense of _save_ is old-fashioned and literary.